# issues with class library using nested name spaces

Tags: c#, namespaces, class-library

**EDIT:**
I have a class library that is growing rapidly and I've decided to organize it a little...
The class library namespaces are structured like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;
using CrystalDecisions.Web;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    namespace FirstNS
    {
        public class Class1
        {
            ReportDocument report = new ReportDocument();

            public static void ShowMe()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Class1");
            }
        }
    }
    namespace SecondNS
    {
        public class Class2
        {
            public static void ShowMe()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Class2");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It compiles fine. When I try to consume the compiled dll by referencing it in a console application I can reference the namespace with the using directive. However when I try to build the application it says "the type or namespace name 'ClassLibrary1' could not be found...".

I've figured out that taking out the CrystalDecisions assemblies fixes the problem I am just unsure why. - As weird as it sounds somehow the problem relates to having nested namespaces. If I use separate namespaces the problem's gone.

Comment: Can we see some example code in those namespaces, and also calling code. I'm assuming you are doing both `using a.b; using a.c;`?

Comment: Do you have any class names that are the same as namespace names? A short but complete example would really help here...

Comment: @Matthew: It doesn't seem to matter how I call it, but let's say I call only one. @Jon: No. Class names are different.
I have edited the post...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, based on your example and error it sounds like the main application which references your library doesn't have access to the crystal assemblies.

In your main app, add references to crystal OR at the very least put those assemblies in your bin directory.  Because the main app can't locate all of the necessary parts for your assembly, it can't use it.

Comment: My example was wrong, sorry... You are right I should have mentioned that the assembly name preceeds the namespace as in your example. Thus unfortunately this is not what is causing the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help so far Chris. Unfortunately that is one of the things that I tried before... The Crystal assemblies will get highlighted with the same error message then.

Answer (score 1):

Chris's response made me think about accessible assemblies and I realised what the problem was.

The Crystal assemblies are Framework 2 and the main application was Framework 4. Changing the target framework back to 2 fixed the problem. Equally I assume using Framework 4 Crystal assemblies (if they exist) should solve the problem, too.

P.S.: I think the error message could be more helpful though... maybe pointing out that a **resource** is inaccessible rather than the entire class library. :)

Comment: That's interesting as .Net 4 can use assemblies created in an earlier version of .net (like 2/3.5) just fine.  Leads me to believe that there is some other dependency in the crystal stuff that isn't being pulled in automatically.